# Running Volley request in background service

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to use Volley to pull some JSON data from a Service class, but I keep receiving File Cache crashes at `RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);` in the service class.

It works fine in my main application.

**Edit**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.xxx.yyy, PID: 28290
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
>   com.idlctech.etherpooler.PoolerService:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3121)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1530)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5969)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:801)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
>                                                                                 at
>   xxx.yyy.zzz.PoolerService.(PoolerService.java:38)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3118)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1530) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5969)

Comment: can you try replacing this with getApplicationContext(). Also please show us the error message from logcat or if u have wrapped that in a try catch block need to see the error.

Comment: Edited to add logcat for what happens when I do getApplicationContext

Comment: please add the rest of the code in this class so we can understand whats going on. is this in a fragment? try getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Comment: @Manny264, no it's a service.  I can add the code in the bit.

Comment: ma bad. has the service been defined in the android manifest?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I wasn't passing the correct context.

Comment: u should write what context u passed for future reference

Answer (score 1):

Define the service in the manifest.

```
<application ... >
  <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
  ...
</application>
```

Look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) post. With the code you have provided us that's all I can think of.